# problems with JavaScript/CSS when publishing ASP.NET forms to Azure cloud

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, azure

I have an ASP.NET Forms project (VS2013) which is running without any issues locally.
At the same time, when I publish it on Azure, all JavaScript/CSS/images files are missing.
Should I do something specific to work around this issue ?

some more details: 
 this web site is based on the purchased bootstrap template which includes a bunch of JavaScript libs and css files. I moved all JavaScript libs under Scripts folder in my VS project and all css/images under Content folder. After these changes this project is running Ok locally but it looks unusable on Azure because js/css/images are missing on Azure.

Comment: just browser to that css and js in azure, if that shows 404, then those files are not copied to azure.

Comment: When you "moved" the files (libs and scripts) to your Scripts and Content folder for your project, did you include the files in the project?  To do this, in the Solution Explorer, click on the icon to show all files, then expand your Scripts and Content folders.  For the new files you copied, right-click on them and select the option to "include in project".